# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS}

Tags: java, android, securityexception, android-securityexception

I get java.lang.SecurityException when try to `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);` with `final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);` intent. Interesting that this crash happens only on Huawei with Android 5.1 - 5.1.1
I haven't Huawei device. Could you please give me advice what it can be.

Stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity } from ProcessRecord{11b5f1a1 19764:com.myproject.my/u0a167} (pid=19764, uid=10167) not exported from uid 1000
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2448)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3794)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
       at com.myproject.my.utils.PermissionsHelper$2.onClick(PermissionsHelper.java:134)
       at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the stack trace, thanks.

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko, did you find a way to handle this exception?

Comment: @RustamIbragimov I wrapped it to try/catch block and in the catch block, some dialog was shown for the user. In my case, it was the dialog with offering to open settings page manually and give the required permissions.

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko, I have this device, but I cannot find the usage access settings. Did you find it?

Comment: @RustamIbragimov I don't have such device, but on my device with Android M, open Settings - Security - (at the bottom) Apps with usage access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For whatever reason, Huawei left the `<intent-filter>` in place for this activity, but they marked it as not exported. There is no way that you can start the activity. All you can do is catch the exception and explain to the user that you cannot navigate there.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

According to android developer documentation.

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.

**Link :** [ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know it and check if activity existing