# Android security exception when accessing settings

Tags: java, android, android-securityexception

I need to open Usage Stats settings from my application. For most of the phones, everything works fine:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
```

However, there are some phones like Huawei Y6 Pro that throws Security Exception `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity } from ProcessRecord{3f032f8b 18712:com.example.pro/u0a924} (pid=18712, uid=10924) not exported from uid 1000`

Is there a way to check if I can execute `startActivity` and it will not throw any exception?

Comment: [Check this link for your issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43323568/8112590)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check that if the following intent can be performed using this

Kotlin:

```
fun canPerformIntent(context: Context, intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val mgr = context.packageManager
    val list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    return list.size > 0
}
```

Java:

```
public static boolean canPerformIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PackageManager mgr = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }
```

and using like this

```
if (canPerformIntent(this, Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS))) {
            //TODO: start the intent
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try with this :

Add this in ur activity's manifest

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:exported="true">


    </activity>
```

Comment: I think I need to put this inside in activity com.android.settings/.Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity. However, I cannot do that.